# Get all rows from table - with the latest row from another table, with another table based on the latest row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to get all the details from the orders table, with the latest status ID in the orders statuses table, and then the name of that status from the states table.

**orders**

```
id | customer | product
-----------------------
1  | David    | Cardboard Box
```

**Order_to_statuses**

```
id | order | status | updated_at
--------------------------------
1  | 1     | 1      | 2017-05-30 00:00:00
2  | 1     | 3      | 2017-05-28 00:00:00
3  | 1     | 4      | 2017-05-29 00:00:00
4  | 1     | 2      | 2017-05-26 00:00:00
5  | 1     | 5      | 2017-05-05 00:00:00
```

**order_states**

```
id | name 
---------
1  | Pending
2  | Paid
3  | Shipped
4  | Refunded
```

In this instance, I would need to get the `customer` and `product`, with the latest status ID from the order statuses table, and then the name of that state.

How can I do this?

Comment: With that sample data, what's the expected result? (Formatted text here too, please.)

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word - so  a poor choice for a table/column identifier.

Comment: @Strawberry all references to column names are either wrapped in `` or used with their table names.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss - How `order_states` table related to another tables?  Please show us  expected result as  jarlh said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd break this down by first getting the `max(updated_at)` for each `order`, then work to everything else you need.  You can get the max date for each order by using subquery:

```
select  
   s.`order`, 
   s.`status`,
   s.updated_at
from order_to_statuses s
inner join 
(
   select 
       `order`,
       max(updated_at) as updated_at
   from order_to_statuses
   group by `order`
) m
   on s.`order` = m.`order`
   and s.updated_at = m.updated_at
```

Once you get this you now have the order, the status id, and the most recent date. Using this you can then JOIN to the other tables, making your full query:

```
select 
    o.customer,
    o.product,
    ots.updated_at,
    os.name
from orders o
inner join
(
   select  
       s.`order`, 
       s.`status`,
       s.updated_at
   from order_to_statuses s
   inner join 
   (
       select 
           `order`,
           max(updated_at) as updated_at
       from order_to_statuses
       group by `order`
   ) m
       on s.`order` = m.`order`
       and s.updated_at = m.updated_at
) ots
    on o.Id = ots.`order`
inner join order_states os
    on ots.`status` = os.id;
```

See a [demo](http://rextester.com/ITFG98623)

Comment: The first part of the query is returning all of the statuses?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss Which part of the query?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss I'm not seeing that on the demo - http://rextester.com/XND62832 One status and date per order. How does your data differ from what you provided?  If your data is different from the sample you provided, then you should include a larger sample for testing.

Comment: I added a groupBy to the whole query and that fixed the first part. I'll try the second part soon.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss Do you have multiple statuses on the same day?

Comment: I guess max(id) will be more robust.

Comment: @Strawberry Obviously, I interpreted latest as `date` not `Id`, but I guess that's what I get for answering a question that doesn't include desired result.

Comment: Yep. Nice answer though. Gets my vote - even if the OP can't bring themselves to appreciate the effort.

Comment: @ollie latest is the date. But it was returning multiple rows rather than one.

Comment: Infact, its grouping for the first order - but the rest of the orders it doesnt. that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may have some typo, but the idea of the query should be something like this:

```
select orders.id, orders.customer, orders.product, 
       order_to_status.status, staus.name 
from orders, order_to_status, status
where orders.id = order_to_status.order
and order_to_status.status = status.id
and order_to_status.updated_at in (
         SELECT MAX(order_to_status.updated_at)  
         FROM order_to_status
         where order_to_status.order = orders.id
         group by order_to_status.order 
);
```

I ussually don't use joins but with joins it should be like this:

```
select orders.id, orders.customer, orders.product, 
       order_to_status.status, staus.name 
from orders
JOIN order_to_status ON orders.id = order_to_status.order
JOIN status ON order_to_status.status = status.id
where 
order_to_status.updated_at in (
    SELECT MAX(order_to_status.updated_at)  
    FROM order_to_status 
    where order_to_status.order = orders.id
    group by order_to_status.order 
);
```

Note I added a group by I had missed.

EDIT 2

I had an error in the subquery condition.
changed to `where order_to_status.order = orders.id`
also moved the group by after the where clause.

Comment: How would this be done with joins rather than multiple froms?

Comment: This returns a row for each status, rather than grouping them.

Comment: I have corrected an error en the subquery condition, I also aded the status description to the result. I ran the query and seems to work ok. If you downvoted the answer please review that.